# How to fetch Event from Firebase JSON to FullCalendar ??? (google web app)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-apps-script, fullcalendar

This is my JSON from Firebase URL

```
{"allDay":"","end":"2023-02-01 18:00:00","id":"EV1","start":"2023-02-05 09:00:00","title":"Event 1"}
```

And I try to fetch them from firebase direct URL something like
https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/Calendar/Test/EV1.json

but have no luck , Calendar didn't display anything ,I tried events/eventSource

```
     const calendarEl = document.getElementById('delivery-calendar')
        const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
          locale: 'th',
          themeSystem: 'bootstrap5',

/*   Just for Testing
            events: [  
    {
        "allDay": "",
        "title": "Test event 2",
        "id": "822",
        "end": "2023-02-01 21:00:00",
        "start": "2023-02-02 16:00:00"
    }
]
*/

 // events: 'https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/Calendar/Test/EV1.json', // Call it directly ,doesn't work

   eventSources: [
    {
      url: 'https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/Calendar/Test/EV1.json',
      data: function(url){
                return [url] // because some topic said FullCalendar need Array of object so I try to put bracket on it ,still doesn't work!
      }
    }

    ]
        })
        calendar.render()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the comment on your code you said

> FullCalendar need Array of object

...and yes that's correct. If your event source doesn't provide that then you can manipulate the structure by handling the [eventSourceSuccess](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventSourceSuccess) callback. For example:

```
eventSourceSuccess: function(content, response) {
  return [content];
}
```

---

P.S.

`data: function...` will not do anything because an [event source object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source-object) doesn't have a data property. Please always study the documentation carefully to understand what is possible.

Comment: Thank you for you advice ,ADyson . I really new in programming , I tried you code but seem get error response this :

GET https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/Delivery/Test/EV1.JSON?start=2023-01-29T00%3A00%3A00%2B07%3A00&end=2023-03-12T00%3A00%3A00%2B07%3A00 404 (Not Found)

Right now , I'm not sure that Can I fetch JSON data with URL like this ?
https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/Calendar/Test/EV1.json

Comment: Hi. `404 (Not Found)` means that this URL doesn't exist in your firebase. That is nothing to do with the code I have written. I personally don't know much about firebase, so it's difficult to help you with that. I also don't know what data you have stored in your firebase. I'm sure the firebase documentation and tutorials probably tells you how to fetch data from it. From the way you worded your question, it sounded like you were already succeeding in fetching the data, and you just needed to turn it into an array.

Comment: From a very quick search, according to https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data what you're trying to do looks basically the right approach, but presumably, for whatever reason, the exact URL you're using doesn't match any real data in your firebase account.

Comment: I think , 404 (Not Found) came from ,I wrote .JSON instead of .json which can access to json file directly from url ...... (you can try to access with this URL :
https://io-testbase1.firebaseio.com/Delivery/Test/EV2.json

so now after change from JSON to json I got this error instead
----------------------------
index.global.min.js:6 
"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e is not iterable"

Comment: Ok. And what is on line 6 of index.global.min.js? I don't know where that is in your code (if it's even a file you created), but it doesn't seem obviously relevant to anything either of us has shown here.

Comment: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@6.1.4/index.global.min.js

It came from fullcalendar cdn with I have no idea what inside , I tried so many thing to make it work but no luck. So I decided to get json outside and pass it as normal array , until I can find a proper way

`$.getJSON("https://io-testbase1.firebaseio.com/Delivery/Test/EV2.json", function(data){

  const calendarEl = document.getElementById('delivery-calendar')
        const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

          events: [data]  
        })
       calendar.render()

 });`

Comment: Why did you do it like that, instead of the way I showed, which was based on your original code?

Comment: As I said I got "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e is not iterable" from the way you advice and I don't know how to solve it at all

Comment: Oh ok I thought that error was from what you showed in your comment, sorry - I misunderstood

Comment: @Samatcha I made a demo using your JSON file and my code...it seems to work perfectly: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/zYJwmYP

Comment: It's work !!  , even I really don't know what different between your demo and code that I implement (I did exactly what you advice haha) , Anw Thank you so much for your help.